# Do the series "Devs" and "Tales from the Loop" have any connection in terms of who worked on it?

Tags: production, science-fiction, soundtrack, cinematography

I recently watched ["Devs"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt8134186/), and now just started watching ["Tales from the Loop"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt8741290/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1).

What struck me immediately is how both have the same feel. Tranquil scenes, dominated by nature. Similar minimal accompanying soundtracks. Odd scenery; the protagonists seem to mostly ignore (which of course you'd expect to be fairly common for sci-fi, but still something feels similar in the way the production is done).

At a glance, the list of producers, musicians, cinematography, etc. seems distinct. But I can't shake the feeling that they might perhaps be more indirectly connected. Alternatively, it might just showcase a recent sci-fi trend.

Is there any connection?

Comment: I suspect they're just made in the same "style". I really enjoyed DEVS, once I got past the really poor acting from the actress who plays Lily Chan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a word, no. There don't seem to be any significant [production crossovers](https://www.imdb.com/search/common/) between *Devs* and *Tales From the Loop*.

The sole individual who worked on both shows is [Nick Roberts](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm1491780/) who did ['ADR Mixing'](https://www.nfi.edu/adr-mixer/) for both shows.

[image]